# Amount of all goals of one team (from JSON)

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I have a JSON file with football games data

```
[
   {
      "game_id":"258716",
      "game_date_start":"2016-08-15",
      "season": "2016",
      "team_1_id":"119",
      "team_2_id":"120",      
      "team_1_goals_quantity":"2",
      "team_2_goals_quantity":"1",         
   },
   {
      "game_id":"258717",
      "game_date_start":"2016-09-15",
      "season": "2016",
      "team_1_id":"119",
      "team_2_id":"122",      
      "team_1_goals_quantity":"1",
      "team_2_goals_quantity":"1"     
   },
   {
      "game_id":"258718",
      "game_date_start":"2016-07-15",
      "season": "2016",
      "team_1_id":"121",
      "team_2_id":"119",     
      "team_1_goals_quantity":"1",
      "team_2_goals_quantity":"1"      
   }
]
```

Task #1. Count the total number of games for each team

Task #2. Count the total number of goals of a team (across all games)

I'm using Vue.js. I've solved Task #1 this way:

```
 countGames() {     
            var data = this.$store.getters.games; 
            var arr1 = []; 
            var obj1 = {}; 

            //Here I got all unique Team IDs
            function getMatches() { 
                    for (var i in data) {        
                          obj1[data[i].team_1_id] = (obj1[data[i].team_1_id] || 0) + 1;
                          obj1[data[i].team_2_id] = (obj1[data[i].team_2_id] || 0) + 1
                    };      
                    Object.keys(obj1).forEach(function(el, data) {
                        arr1.push( [ el, obj1[el]] );                       
                    });                          
                 }; 
            getMatches();          
            var result = arr1.map(
                  ([team_id, matches]) => ({team_id, matches}) //here I got { {team_id: "119", matches: 3}, {team_id: "120", matches: 1} ... }
            );
            return result;                 
        }
```

It works. But I have no idea how to solve Task #2 - counting the total amount of goals for each team across all games. The problem is that sometimes the team's unique ID may be at team_1_id, and sometimes at team_2_id (like the team "119" i  in JSON example).

Please help me to write this script.

Comment: The `game_id` is always the same? It should be different, right?

Comment: Yes, it is different every time, thank you fore note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on keeping code as it is, you could probably add another object to track goals like this:

```
 function countGames() {
      var data = this.$store.getters.games;      
      var arr1 = []; 
      var goalsPerTeam = []; // keep track of goals here
      var obj1 = {}; 

      //Here I got all unique Team IDs
      function getMatches() { 
              for (var i in data) {        
                    obj1[data[i].team_1_id] = (obj1[data[i].team_1_id] || 0) + 1;
                    obj1[data[i].team_2_id] = (obj1[data[i].team_2_id] || 0) + 1;
                    // add goals count
                    if (goalsPerTeam[data[i].team_1_id] === undefined) {
                      goalsPerTeam[data[i].team_1_id] = parseInt(data[i].team_1_goals_quantity);
                    } else {
                      goalsPerTeam[data[i].team_1_id] += parseInt(data[i].team_1_goals_quantity);
                    }

                    if (goalsPerTeam[data[i].team_2_id] === undefined) {
                      goalsPerTeam[data[i].team_2_id] = parseInt(data[i].team_2_goals_quantity);
                    } else {
                      goalsPerTeam[data[i].team_2_id] += parseInt(data[i].team_2_goals_quantity);
                    }
              };      
              Object.keys(obj1).forEach(function(el, data) {
                  arr1.push( [ el, obj1[el], goalsPerTeam[el]] );  // update this                   
              });                          
           }; 
        getMatches();          
        var result = arr1.map(
              // add here finally
              ([team_id, matches, goals]) => ({team_id, matches, goals}) //here I got { {team_id: "119", matches: 3}, {team_id: "120", matches: 1} ... }
        );
        return result;                 
      }
```

Comment: Your solution worked for me, but partially. Somehow it counts only gouls in the last game that the team was played, not the sum of all goals. So I got "119": 1 goals, instead of "119": 3 goals. Can you tell what could be a reason?

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't test it very well before. Please check the edited answer.
With this example data it derives i.e. for team '119': 4 goals (2 + 1 + 1).

Answer (score 1):

You can map through each object of the array and increment the corresponding counter to get your data like this:

```
    let totalGames = {},
        totalGoals = {};

    data.map( game => {

        //count games team 1
        if (!totalGames.hasOwnProperty(game.team_1_id)) {
            totalGames[game.team_1_id] = 1;
        } else {
            totalGames[game.team_1_id] += 1;
        }
        //count games team 2
        if (!totalGames.hasOwnProperty(game.team_2_id)) {
            totalGames[game.team_2_id] = 1;
        } else {
            totalGames[game.team_2_id] += 1;
        }

        //count goals team 1
        if (!totalGoals.hasOwnProperty(game.team_1_id)) {
            totalGoals[game.team_1_id] = parseInt(game.team_1_goals_quantity);
        } else {
            totalGoals[game.team_1_id] += parseInt(game.team_1_goals_quantity);
        }

        //count goals team 2
        if (!totalGoals.hasOwnProperty(game.team_2_id)) {
            totalGoals[game.team_2_id] = parseInt(game.team_2_goals_quantity);
        } else {
            totalGoals[game.team_2_id] += parseInt(game.team_2_goals_quantity);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just focusing on the counting of goals, my solution would be creating a dictionary with just team-goal pairs and then summarizing that into a team-goalnumber array:

```
function count_team_goals(json){

   // create a summary json
   let summ = []
   for(i in json){
      team_1 = {'team': json[i]['team_1_id'], 'goals': json[i]['team_1_goals_quantity']};
      team_2 = {'team': json[i]['team_2_id'], 'goals': json[i]['team_2_goals_quantity']};
      summ.push(team_1)
      summ.push(team_2);
   }

   // count the team goals with reduce and return
   let summ_d = summ.reduce(function(e, c) {
      e[c.team] = e[c.team] || {'team_id': c.team, 'goals': 0};
      e[c.team]['goals'] = e[c.team]['goals'] + parseInt(c.goals);
      return e;
   }, {})

   // return array
   return Object.keys(summ_d).map(k => summ_d[k])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
const getResultsByTeamId = (id) => {
  const matches = list
    .filter((match) => match.team_1_id === id || match.team_2_id === id)

  const goals = matches
    .map((match) => match.team_1_id === id
      ? match.team_1_goals_quantity
      : match.team_2_goals_quantity)
    .reduce((acc, goals) => acc + parseInt(goals), 0)

  return {
    matches: matches.length,
    goals
  }
}
```

and then call

```
// The argument is a string because your ID is a string, not a number.
getResultsByTeamId('119') #returns { matches: 3, goals: 4 }
getResultsByTeamId('120') #returns { matches: 1, goals: 1 }
getResultsByTeamId('121') #returns { matches: 1, goals: 1 }
getResultsByTeamId('122') #returns { matches: 1, goals: 1 }
```

Quick explanation: First you filter the matches that have the team either as team 1 or team 2. Then you get only the goals of the team, and then you sum.